# Make DB calls through different models atomic

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, anorm

Let's say that there are two models, `Model1` and `Model2`, each model has a set of basic methods that call DB to retrieve or write data. For one `Model1` there can exist multiple `Model2`, when inserting a `(Model1, List[Model2])` all this data comes from the same form. The current implementation does the following:

1. Insert the `Model1` instance using `Model1`'s insert method.
2. When `Model1` has been correctly inserted, proceed with inserting the `List[Model2]` using `Model2`'s insert method.

The issue is that if an issue occurs while inserting one of the `Model2`, `Model1` will remain in DB. A solution would be to catch any exception that `anorm` throws and undo whatever was executed before by doing the exact opposite of it. But is there a solution already out there that can be used? Something that captures all DB calls that were executed and revert them if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `DB.withTransaction`. It works exactly the same as `DB.withConnection`, except that `autocommit` is set to `false`, so that if any exceptions are thrown, the entire transaction will be rolled back.

Example:

```
case class Model1(id: Long, something: String, children: List[Model2])

case class Model2(id: Long, name: String)

object Model1 {

    def create(model: Model1): Option[Model1] = {
        DB.withTransaction { implicit c =>
            SQL(...).executeInsert().map { id =>
                 model.copy(
                     id = id,
                     children = Model2.create(model.children)
                 )
            }
        }
    }

}

object Model2 {

    def create(models: List[Model2])(implicit c: java.sql.Connection): List[Model2] = {
       ...
    }

}
```

Note how `Model2.create` accepts an implicit `Connection` parameter. This is so that it will use the same `Connection` as the `Model1.create` transaction, and be allowed to roll back on failure. I've left out the fine implementation details, as the key is just using `withTransaction`, and running each query on the same `Connection`.